# Using #define in resource scripts

Tags: c++, windows, header, resources

I want to redefine an automatically generated value in a resource script. I *know* how to do that, I *did* that in legacy Visual C++ 6 and Code::Blocks. Here's the general structure of my Resource.rc file:

```
#include "resource.h" // automatically generated IDs
#include <windows.h> // carries definitions of basic constants
#include "redefinition.h" // redefinition of automatically generated IDs
... // body of the resource script
```

For instance, the following line in Redefinition.h would "override" the symbol ID named MY_VAL with a more suitable value:

```
#define MY_VAL 100*50+22 // 5022
```

When I try to use the same concept in Visual Studio 2010 Express, it literaly *ignores* the multiplication! That is:

```
#define MY_VAL 100*50+22 // VS sees 100+22 = 122
#define MY_VAL 50*100+22 // VS sees 50+22 = 72
```

Parentheses don't help! Hence, is there any constraint put on the Express edition in that macro evaluation is limited to mere additions/subtractions in this context, or am I really stupid? (Or are those at Microsoft?!)

Many thanks for a help/advice.

Comment: Since I can't see any reason you would write your value a 100*50+22, instead of just writing 5022, could I assume that you are actually using define parameters? Was this example simplified? Could you show the actual version? I can't fathom any reason why VS would misinterpret this, unless there is more to it.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't do arithmetic - it just replaces `MY_VAL` with the sequence of characters `100*50+22` and passes it along to the compiler. The resource compiler (unlike the C or C++ compiler) doesn't do arithmetic either - .rc file syntax calls for plain integer literals, not arbitrary arithmetic expressions. I'm surprised your code compiles at all; in any case, this approach ain't gonna fly.

Comment: @BadWolf: Hi, thanks for the response. Of course it has been simplified - the arithmetics is to encode some more information into the ID.; for instance, the following is to supply a menu item with an "ID" of its containing menu: #define IDM_DOMAIN_NEW IDM_DOMAIN*IDM_MENU_BASE+1. Having to do this because the Win32++ framework somehow passes WM_MENUCOMMAND messages (with handle to the menu in lParam) to a different window than the owner of the menu. Strange, hence all this mess to compress both the menu

Comment: @BadWolf: (reformulated the previous comment) Hi, thanks for the response. Of course it has been simplified - the arithmetics is to encode some more information into the ID. In fact, I'm attempting to imitate the functionality of the WM_MENUCOMMAND messages (with handle to the menu in lParam). This message doesn't work as expected in the Win32++ framework I'm playing with - the message is passed to a different window than the menu owner. Hence, the workaround is to supply each menu item with an "ID" of its containing menu, e.g. #define IDM_DOMAIN_NEW IDM_DOMAIN*IDM_MENU_BASE+1.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: And consider that VS6 allows even parentheses and multiplication while CodeBlocks swallows even bit shift operators! :-)

Comment: Yet one comment, here I extracted the problem into a minimalistic example, [link](http://nestorovic.hyperlink.cz/__comms__/experiment.zip). Can anyone please confirm that the same happens even in VS2010Pro? (Just curious if the arithmetics is limited in the Express version.) Have already found another workaround, so it's become nothing serious (just even more cumbersome....). Thanks.